# mat-table directive is not rendering at full width

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm having a strange issue where the `mat-table` directive on a `table` element is not rendering all the way across. There are no custom styles associated with table, mat-table, or any elements inside of a table.

[image: table collapsed example]

Table component example:

`<datatable [data]="data" [headers]"headers"></datatable>`

Table Code:

```
<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let header of headers" [matColumnDef]="header.value">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [disabled]="!sorting">
            {{header.name}}
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            {{element[header.value]}}
        </td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, I'm generating the headers using *ngFor rather than defining each column. Here are the headers and data I'm using for this example:

```
headers: ITableHeader[] = [
    { name: 'ID', value: 'id' },
    { name: 'Name', value: 'name' },
    { name: 'Address', value: 'address' },
];
data = [
    { id: 0, name: 'name 0', address: 'address 0' },
    { id: 1, name: 'name 1', address: 'address 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'name 2', address: 'address 2' },
    { id: 3, name: 'name 3', address: 'address 3' },
];
```

The component initializes with a blank `MatTableDataSource`. On data change, data is set by `this.dataSource.data = this.data;`

I've checked the element inspector after going over each element and can't figure out what is different from a regular table. Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution showed itself when I added Bootstrap's `table` class. I assumed a table by default would fill the parent container.

To fix this issue, create a class that has the property `width: 100%` and add it to the `table` element. Bootstrap already has a helper class if you use that: `w-100`.

```
<table class="w-100" mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource">
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the mat-table tag instead of the table tag and remove the mat-table directive:

```
<mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource">
```

instead of

```
<table mat-table matSort [dataSource]="dataSource">
```

Comment: Fixed for me. Thank you.